# Failed to dial: handshake failed: ssh: no common algorithms Error in ssh client for golang

Tags: ssh, go

I'm working on a project that is using [goftp](https://github.com/jlaffaye/goftp) to upload to a server, but (thanks to the kind people here) I will use a more secure method.

I plan to use ssh instead and found this ssh client in golang found [here](https://gist.github.com/linuz-ly/4148437).

I have setup an ssh server (freeSSHd) and can successfully connect through PuTTY both locally and on another machine.

I have only changed this part of the client to replace the variables with my own

```
var (
    server = "127.0.0.1:22"
    username = "username"
    password = clientPassword("password")
)
```

When I execute the ssh client, ssh.Dial returns an error, and the panic displays this: 
**"Failed to dial: handshake failed: ssh: no common algorithms"**

```
client, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", "127.0.0.1:22", config)
if err != nil {
    panic("Failed to dial: " + err.Error())
}
```

I am new to golang so I would appreciate any help to point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This thread may be helpful: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/UftJqQcJ1nA/_MufYD1ODw4J

In short - looks like goland doesn't support the algo used by freeSSHd

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the [source code](https://github.com/golang/crypto/blob/master/ssh/cipher.go#L95) for the `go.crypto/ssh` package, we can see that the supported ciphers are the following:

- aes128-ctr
- aes192-ctr
- aes256-ctr
- arcfour128
- arcfour256

While freeSSHd supports:

- aes128-cbc
- aes192-cbc
- aes256-cbc
- 3des-cbc
- blowfish-cbc
- rijndael128-cbc
- rijndael192-cbc
- rijndael256-cbc
- rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se

Because the client and server shares no common cipher, you will get the error message. The reason why CBC mode is not supported in the ssh package is most likely because of a [vulnerability](http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/958563), as discussed in [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/J2XCsTsNQ9o)  golang-nuts thread.

A solution to your problem might be to try install a different SSH server, such as [OpenSSH for Windows](http://sshwindows.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Great! I'll try OpenSSH for Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Though it is **insecure** you can get go's library to use a cypher supported by freeSSH.

```
sshConfig.Config.Ciphers = append(sshConfig.Config.Ciphers, "aes128-cbc")
```